# How to insert default values from one table to other in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables, one named `employees`, one `Documents`, and one `Doctemplates`

`employees` and `documents` have relationship, and `doctemplates` contain several `document` names.

What I need is when i add a new `employee`, under documents, system add the defaults documents templates form table `doctemplates`, so i don't have to type one by one.

Is there any way to do this, in a mysql query or php?

Comment: Could you provide table details?

Comment: Table employee:
ID ,
Name

Table DOcument:
ID
EmployeeID
DocumentNAme

DOctemplates:
ID
DocumentNAme

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO documents (employeeId, col1, col2, col3)
SELECT $employeeId, c1, c2, c3 FROM doctemplates;
```

You can do it manually or from trigger.

More info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Hello, thanks for help me, do you have any idea how can i insert the employee  id to this query when i add a new employee. i try your code manually and work perfect, thanks

Comment: From post insert trigger you will need to use NEW.Id. From php you will need to call insert_id to get id for just created emploee and then put it into new query.

Answer (score -1):

WHAT YOU WANT IS TO INSERT DATA FROM DOCTEMPLETS TO DOCUMENTS.FOR THIS YOU HAVE TO CREATE A RELATION BETWEEN EMPLOYEE AND DOCTEMPLETS,THEN DEFINE A FOREIGN KEY IN DOCUMENTS TABLE FROM DOCTEMPLETS.
IF YOU WANT MORE ABOUT FOREIGN KEY DEFINING.PLZ ASK NEXT.
THANS

Comment: Hi and Welcome to StackOverflow, Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Ok this way is different, so for example i have employee id in employre table, this is in relationship with employeeid under documents, so how could be the relationship using foreign key? thanks

Comment: you can define foreign key only when creating table.